# Flex 4 Spark List Itemrender

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Here is my itemRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true"
                width="100%" height="40"
                click="adCanvas.selected=data.object;" mouseDown="adCanvas.selected=data.object;"
                creationComplete="init()" initialize="trace('initializing')" activate="checkActions()" dataChange="checkActions()" render="checkActions()">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import adBuilder.*;

        import components.AdCanvas;

        import events.AdLoadEvent;

        import flash.display.Bitmap;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.utils.describeType;

        import interfaces.IAdObject;

        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
        import mx.utils.*;

        [Bindable] private var desc:String;
        private var adCanvas:AdCanvas;
        private var adBuilder:AdBuilder;
        [Bindable]private var myvis:Boolean=false;
        private const MAX_NAME_LENGTH:Number = 19;

        private function init():void {
            trace("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! LAYER RENDERER !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (!data) data = {};
            if (data.hasOwnProperty("first")) {
                toggleEnabled(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.btnUp);
            }
            if (data.hasOwnProperty("last")) {
                toggleEnabled(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.btnDown);
            }

            adCanvas = data.adCanvas;
            if(IAdObject(data.object as IAdObject)){
                if(IAdObject(data.object).animationObjects){
                    IAdObject(data.object).animationObjects.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, checkActions);
                    checkActions();

                }
            }

            iconType.source = findSource();

        }

        private function checkActions(e:Event=null):void{
            try{
                if(data){
                    if(IAdObject(data.object as IAdObject)){
                        if(IAdObject(data.object as IAdObject).animationObjects){
                            if(data.object.animationObjects.length>0){
                                this.myvis=true;
                            }else{
                                this.myvis=false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                iconType.source = findSource();
            }catch(error:Error){
                trace("LayerRenderer.mxml - checkActions(): " + error.message); 
            }
        }

        private function toggleEnabled(obj:UIComponent):void {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty("first")) {
                obj.useHandCursor = false;
                obj.enabled = false;
                obj.alpha = 0.5; 
            } else {
                obj.useHandCursor = true;
                obj.enabled = true;
                obj.alpha = 1;
            }
            iconType.source = findSource();
        }

        private function hideLayers():void{
            //dispatchEvent(new Event("Layer_Visible"));
            trace("CLICKED EYE");
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(new Event('Layer_Visible'));
            if (hideLayer.alpha == 1){
                hideLayer.alpha = .5;
            }

            else if (hideLayer.alpha == .5){
                hideLayer.alpha = 1;
            }
            //trace("parameters are " + ObjectUtil.toString(data));
        }

        private function findSource():*{
            if (data){
                //iconType.source = "";
                if (data.type == "Image"){
                    //trace("data.name: " + data.name);
                    //trace("data.bitmapinfo: " + data.bitmapinfo);     
                    return new Bitmap(data.bitmapinfo);
                }

                if (data.type == "Text"){
                    return("assets/images/Text2.png");
                }

                if (data.type == "Application"){
                    return
                    //return("assets/images/App.png");
                }

                if (data.type == "Button"){
                    return("assets/images/Button.png");
                }

                if (data.type == "Shape"){
                    return("assets/images/shape.png");
                }

                if (data.type == "SWF"){
                    return("assets/images/SWF.png");
                }

                else{
                    return "assets/images/placeholder.png";
                }
            }
            else {
                return "assets/images/placeholder.png";
            }
        }

        private function truncateName(nameStr:String):String
        {
            var returnVal:String = (nameStr.indexOf(".") > -1) ? nameStr.substr(0, nameStr.indexOf(".")) : nameStr; 
            var extension:String = (nameStr.indexOf(".") > -1) ? nameStr.substr(nameStr.indexOf("."),nameStr.length) : "";

            //trace("nameStr: " + nameStr);
            //trace("extension: " + extension);

            if (returnVal.length > MAX_NAME_LENGTH){
                returnVal = returnVal.substr(0,MAX_NAME_LENGTH) + "...";
            }/*else{
            returnVal += extension;
            }*/

            return returnVal;
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Group id="layerGroup" width="100%" height="100%" top="10" left="5" bottom="10" right="10">
        <s:HGroup left="0" verticalAlign="middle" width="100%">
            <s:HGroup paddingBottom="40" paddingRight="10">
                <mx:Image id="iconType" smoothBitmapContent="true" scaleContent="true" source="" height="20" width="20"/>
            </s:HGroup> 
            <s:HGroup width="100%">
                <s:Label toolTip="{data.name}" text="{truncateName(data.name)}" id="labelText" height="50" top="5" width="100%" maxDisplayedLines="1" left="0" color="#101010"/>
                <s:Label toolTip="" text="{Math.ceil(data.fileSize/1000)+' K'}" textAlign="right" id="sizeText" height="50" top="5" width="70" maxDisplayedLines="1" left="0" color="#101010"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup paddingBottom="40">
                <mx:Image horizontalAlign="right" bottom="10" alpha="1" right="2" id="hideLayer" verticalAlign="middle" source="assets/images/visible.png" click="hideLayers()" useHandCursor="true"/>
                <mx:Image id="actLabel" includeInLayout="false" visible="{this.myvis}" source="assets/images/star.png" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:Group>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Here is the class that uses said renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   left="5" top="10" bottom="0"
                   creationComplete="init();" rollOver="rolledOver(event)" rollOut="rolledOut(event)" 
                   backgroundColor="#F0F0F0" backgroundAlpha="1" borderAlpha="0" borderColor="#3a3a3a" width="100%" height="60" currentState="out">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="over"/>
        <s:State name="out" />
    </s:states>

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        import components.*;
        import components.AdCanvas;

        import events.AdCanvasObjectEvent;

        import flash.system.LoaderContext;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Image;
        import mx.core.Application;
        import mx.core.DragSource;
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.core.IUIComponent;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.events.DragEvent;
        import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
        import mx.managers.DragManager;

        import spark.components.Group;
        import spark.layouts.*;

        [Bindable]
        private var _data: Object;

        [Bindable] 
        private var context:LoaderContext;
        [Bindable]
        public var canvas: AdCanvas;

        [Bindable]
        public var index: int;

        [Bindable]
        public var maxPreviewWidth: int;
        [Bindable]
        public var maxPreviewHeight: int;

        [Bindable]
        public var isSelected: Boolean = false;

        [Bindable]
        private var adRect:Rectangle;

        [Bindable]
        private var ad:BitmapData;

        [Bindable] 
        public var layerData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        [Bindable]
        private var application:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;
        //public var layerList:List;

        private const MAX_HEIGHT:Number = 400;
        private const MINIMUM_HEIGHT:Number = 60;

        private var t:Timer;
        private var t2:Timer;
        private var t3:Timer;

        [Bindable]private var siblings:Array = new Array();

        /**
         * Initialize the preview item
         */
        public function init(obj: Object = null): void {
            //layersList.data = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.getLayerList();
            //trace("Layer data " + layersList.data);

            canvas.screenPreview = this;

            context = new LoaderContext(false);

            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(AdCanvasObjectEvent.UPDATED, updateThumbnail);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(AdCanvasObjectEvent.ADDED, updateThumbnail);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(AdCanvasObjectEvent.DELETED, updateThumbnail);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(AdCanvasObjectEvent.SELECTED_SINGLE, updateThumbnail);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(AdCanvasObjectEvent.SELECTED_MULTIPLE, updateThumbnail);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(AdCanvasObjectEvent.DESELECT, updateThumbnail);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener("updateThumbnail", updateThumbnail);

            // This is to prevent the security error when there is a loaded swf trying to be accessed for bitmap

            Security.loadPolicyFile(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.mediaUrl+"../crossdomain.xml");*/

            //if(root.loaderInfo.url.indexOf('file://')==-1)img.loaderContext = new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, SecurityDomain.currentDomain);
            canvas.updatePreview();
            buildThumb();
            titleBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
            (adCanvas.isDeletable || adCanvas.isDeletable == "true") ? screenDelete.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick) : null;

            //layersList.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_ENTER, handleDragEnter);
            //layersList.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_DROP, handleDragDrop);
            //layersList.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_START, handleDragStart);

            this.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_ENTER, handleDragEnter);
            this.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_DROP, handleDragScreenDrop);

            //setHeight();
            //setYPos();
        }

        private function handleDragStart(event:DragEvent):void{
            try{
                var obj:Object = (event.dragInitiator as List).selectedItem;
                canvas.selected = obj["object"];
            }catch (error:Error){
                trace("ERROR: ScreenPreview.mxml - handleDragStart() : " + error.message);
            }
        }

        private function handleDragEnter(event:DragEvent):void {
            trace("event.dragInitiator: " + event.dragInitiator);

            if( event.dragInitiator is List){
                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(this);
                DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.MOVE);
                layersList.dropEnabled = true;
            }else{
                layersList.dropEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private function handleDragDrop(event:DragEvent):void {             
            t = new Timer(500);
            t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkLayerData);
            t.start();
        }

        private function handleDragScreenDrop(event:DragEvent):void {
            /*trace("\n");
            trace("TEEEEE HEEEEEE");
            trace("event.target: " + event.target);
            trace("event.currentTarge:  " + event.currentTarget);
            trace("this: " + this);
            trace("event.dragInitiator: " + (event.dragInitiator as List).selectedItem);
            trace("event.draggedItem: " + event.draggedItem);
            trace("event.dragSource: " + event.dragSource);
            */
            try
            {
                var obj:Object = (event.dragInitiator as List).selectedItem;
                var clone:UIComponent = obj["element"].clone();

                /*for( var i:* in obj)
                {
                trace( "obj["+i+"]: " + obj[i]);
                }

                trace("obj: " + obj);
                */
                this.canvas.addObjectToCanvas(clone);

                obj["adCanvas"].removeScreenElement(obj);
            }catch(error:Error){
                trace("ERROR: ScreenPreview - handleDragDrop() : " + error.message);
            }
            //trace("\n");
        }

        private function checkLayerData(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            t.stop();
            t = null;

            adCanvas.updateItemIndex();

        }

        public function setSizeText(val:Number):void
        {
            sizeText.text = (Math.ceil(val/1000) + " K");

            if (isSelected)
            {
                t3 = new Timer(100);
                t3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayResize);
                t3.start();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update the bitmap data for the screen when something has changed.
         */
        public function updateThumbnail(ev: AdCanvasObjectEvent = null): void {
            try{
                canvas.gridOff();
                var adRect:Rectangle = canvas.adBox.getBounds(canvas);
                var snapshot: BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData((canvas as IBitmapDrawable));
                var ad:BitmapData = new BitmapData(adRect.width, adRect.height);
                ad.copyPixels(snapshot, adRect, new Point());
                img.source = new Bitmap(ad);
                canvas.gridOn();

            }catch(e:Error){
                trace(e+"System can't convert external swf files to bitmap.");
                canvas.gridOn();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Controls visuals for when the button is selected.
         */
        public function set selected(state: Boolean): void 
        {
            isSelected = state;

            trace("MY STATE IS: " + state);

            if (isSelected) 
            {
                layersList.includeInLayout=true;
                stroke.color=0x878787;
                strokeColor.color=0x878787;
                bg.color = 0x979fa7;
                layersList.visible = true;
                //layersList.percentHeight = 100;
                screenSettings.visible = true;
                (adCanvas.isDeletable || adCanvas.isDeletable == "true") ? screenDelete.visible = true : screenDelete.visible = false;
                //percentHeight=100;

                siblings.splice(0,siblings.length);
                siblings = new Array();
                try 
                {
                    for(var i:int=0; i < Group(parent).numChildren; i++)
                    {                   
                        siblings.push(Group(parent).getElementAt(i));
                    }
                }
                catch (e:Error) {}

                t2 = new Timer(100);
                t2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayResize);
                t2.start();
            } 
            else 
            {
                stroke.color=0x3C3C3C;
                strokeColor.color=0x3C3C3C;
                bg.color = 0x636B73;
                currentState="out";
                layersList.includeInLayout=false;
            }
        }

        private function delayResize(evt:TimerEvent):void{

            if(t2){
                t2.stop();
                t2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayResize);
                t2 = null;
            }

            if(t3){
                t3.stop();
                t3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayResize);
                t3 = null;
            }
            setHeight();
            setYPos();
        }

        public function setYPos():void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < siblings.length; i++)
            {
                if(i>0)
                {
                    siblings[i].y = ( siblings[i-1].y + siblings[i-1].height); 
                }

                if (siblings[i] != this){
                    ScreenPreview(siblings[i]).selected = false;
                    ScreenPreview(siblings[i]).checkLayer();
                }
            }
        }

        public function setHeight():void
        {               
            for(var i:int = 0; i < siblings.length; i++)
            {                   
                if( siblings[i] == this )
                {
                    if( (MINIMUM_HEIGHT + totLayersHeight()) > MAX_HEIGHT){
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }else{
                        height = MINIMUM_HEIGHT + totLayersHeight();
                    }
                }

                trace("###################################################");
                trace("ScreenPreview - canvas: " + canvas);
                trace("ScreenPreview - canvas.href: " + canvas.href);
                trace("ScreenPreview - canvas.click_label: " + canvas.click_label);
                trace("###################################################");

                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setMouseActionsFromObject();
            }
        }

        private function totLayersHeight():Number{
            trace("this.layerData.length: " + this.layerData.length);
            var val:Number = 0;
            //multiply by 40 because that is the height of each layer item
            if( this.layerData.length > 0) val = (this.layerData.length + 1) * 40;
            return val;
        }

        public function checkLayer ():void{
            screenSettings.visible = false;
            screenDelete.visible = false;
            layersList.visible = false;
            //percentHeight=15;
            height = 60;
        }

        /**
         * Controls visuals for when the button is rolled over.
         */
        private function rolledOver(e:Event):void
        {
            str.color=0xffc423;
            bg.color=0xBAC2CA;
        }

        /**
         * Controls visuals for when the button is rolledout.
         */
        private function rolledOut(e:Event):void{
            if(!isSelected){
                bg.color=0x636B73;

                /*g1.color=0xCBCBCB;
                g2.color=0xD9D9D9;
                str.color=0xCBCBCB;
                lg.rotation=-90;*/
            }else{
                bg.color=0x979fa7;

                /*g1.color=0xCBCBCB;
                g2.color=0xCBCBCB;
                str.color=0xCBCBCB;
                lg.rotation=90*/
            }
        }


        /**
         * Set up the canvas and SWF sizes, as well as label, for the screen thumbnail.
         */
        public function buildThumb():void{
            adRect = new Rectangle(15, 15, canvas.adBox.width, canvas.adBox.height);
            ad = new BitmapData(adRect.width + 100, adRect.height + 100, true, 0);
            setImageSize();
            labelText.text = "Screen "+canvas.index;//+": "+canvas.adWidth+"x"+canvas.adHeight;
            updateThumbnail();
        }

        /**
         * Get the scaled-down screen size.
         */
        private function getScaledDimensions(targetHeight:int=100, targetWidth:int=100): Object {
            var xScaleFactor: Number = (maxPreviewWidth > targetWidth) ? (targetWidth/maxPreviewWidth) : 1;
            var yScaleFactor: Number = (maxPreviewHeight > targetHeight) ? (targetHeight/maxPreviewHeight) : 1;
            var scaleFactor: Number = (xScaleFactor < yScaleFactor) ? xScaleFactor : yScaleFactor;

            var dimensions: Object = {
                width: Math.round(adRect.width * scaleFactor),
                    height: Math.round(adRect.width * scaleFactor)
            }

            return dimensions;
        }

        /**
         * Change the the thumb size and position based on the ad size.
         */
        private function setImageSize():void
        {
            var w:Number = adRect.width + 100;
            var h:Number = adRect.height + 100;
            var scaler:Number = (w>h)?40/w:27/h;
            img.width = w*scaler;
            img.height = h*scaler;
            rolledOut(null);

            imgBox.left = 10;

            if (w > (h*2)){
                imgBox.top=15;
            }

            if (h > (w*2)){
                imgBox.top = 5;
            }   
        }

        private function mouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("did the click");

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            if( e.currentTarget == screenDelete)
            {
                trace("DISPATCH DELETE SCREEN");
                dispatchEvent(new Event('delete_screen_click'));
            }else{
                trace("DISPATCH MOUSE CLICK");
                dispatchEvent(new Event('mouse_click'));
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(new AdCanvasObjectEvent(AdCanvasObjectEvent.DESELECT));
            }
            //FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.updateLayerScreens();
        }

        private function deleteThisScreen(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event('delete_screen_click'));
        }

        /**
         * Getter and setter for adcanvas that we are using for the thumbnail
         */
        public function set adCanvas(canv: AdCanvas): void {
            canvas = canv;
            index = canv.index;
        }
        public function get adCanvas(): AdCanvas {
            return canvas;
        }

        /**
         * Getter for checking if this button has been selected.
         */
        public function get selected(): Boolean {
            return isSelected;
        }

        private function settingsMenu():void{
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(new AdCanvasObjectEvent(AdCanvasObjectEvent.DESELECT));
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.openSettings();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup left="1" right="1" top="1" height="100%" width="100%" paddingBottom="5">
        <s:VGroup id="titleBar" height="55" top="20" width="100%">
            <s:HGroup top="5" left="5" height="100%" width="100%">
                <s:Group width="55" height="50">
                    <s:Rect id="fill" left="5" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" radiusX="0">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:SolidColor id="bg" color="0x979fa7"/>
                        </s:fill>
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:SolidColorStroke id="stroke" color="0x3C3C3C" alpha="1"/>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>
                    <s:HGroup id="vg" height="50" width="100%" gap="0">
                        <s:Group height="15" top="2" width="100%">
                            <s:VGroup top="5" id="imgBox" width="15">
                                <mx:Image left="5" id="img" scaleContent="true" height="50" width="50" top="10" />
                            </s:VGroup>
                        </s:Group>
                    </s:HGroup>
                    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="0" >
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:SolidColorStroke id="str" color="0x979fa7" weight="2" alpha="0" />
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>
                </s:Group>
                <s:Group left="0" top="0" height="60" width="100%">
                    <s:Rect top="0" left="5" right="0" bottom="0" bottomLeftRadiusX="0" bottomRightRadiusX="0">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:SolidColor id="bg2" color="0xDCE4EC" alpha="0"/>
                        </s:fill>
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:SolidColorStroke id="strokeColor" color="0x3C3C3C" alpha="0"/>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>
                    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" top="15" width="100%">
                        <mx:Text id="labelText" text="" selectable="false" color="#3a3a3a" width="100%" fontSize="10" textAlign="center" />
                        <mx:Text id="sizeText" text="" selectable="false" color="#3a3a3a" width="100%" fontSize="10" textAlign="right" />
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:Group>
                <s:Group>
                    <mx:Image source="assets/images/trashcan-delete.png" visible="false" toolTip="Delete This Screen" id="screenDelete" top="15" right="45" useHandCursor="true"/>
                    <mx:Image source="assets/images/cog.png" visible="false" toolTip="Edit Screen Settings" top="15" right="11" id="screenSettings" click="settingsMenu()" useHandCursor="true"/>
                </s:Group>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
        <s:VGroup id="layerPanel" includeInLayout="true" paddingBottom="1" height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:List creationComplete="{trace('TEEEEEEEEEEEEE HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE')}"
                id="layersList" 
                dragStart="{handleDragStart(event)}" dragEnter="{handleDragEnter(event)}" dragDrop="{handleDragDrop(event)}"
                dragEnabled="true"
                dropEnabled="true"
                dragMoveEnabled="true"
                includeInLayout="true"
                visible="true"
                initialize="application.setUpLayers()"
                dataProvider='{layerData}'
                selectedIndex="{application.getLayerListIndex()}"
                render='{layersList.selectedIndex=application.getLayerListIndex()}'
                itemRenderer="renderers.LayerRenderer"
                width="100%" 
                height="100%"
                bottom="50"
                alternatingItemColors="[#e2e2e2, #dedede]"
                selectionColor="#787878" 
                rollOverColor="#949494"
                borderVisible="false"
                />
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:BorderContainer>
```

The problem I'm having is the itemRenderer never gets called.  I put trace statements just to be sure and nothing.  These two files once used mx:canvas and were converted. I've been beating my head against a wall for 2 days with this issue.  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I do not see any place where where any objects are put into the layerData dataProvider; as such the list has no reason to create any instance of the itemRenderer.  Just a guess, though.  Can you get rid of all your "Extra" code and just give us enough to demo the problem?

Comment: The array collection layerData is being passed into the dataProvider, it's bindable so when it gets updated so too should the list.  layerData is being populated in another part of the code. I know that the layerData is populated b/c I can see the data in a trace statement.  THis isn't something that I can dumb down or upload completely here, work related.

Comment: I understand how binding works.  However, there is no place in your provided code.  If you're not able to provide a short, self-contained, correct, compilable sample I'm not sure we can help you: http://sscce.org/ Just create a main application with a hard coded dataProvider, the List, and the itemRenderer you already have.